# Syntax error when using priorvalue in formula

Tags: formula, picklist

I am just learning the priorvalue formula.
I want a workflow to trigger when the status of my contract changes from `On Hold` to `Activated`.

I created the following and I am getting syntax error:

```
AND(
ISCHANGED(Status), 
TEXT(PRIORVALUE(Status))="On Hold",
TEXT(Status)=”Activated”
)
```

Comment: doesn't look like the syntax error was added to the question? You can [edit] and add the error you're getting. Likewise, as `Status` is a picklist you'll want to look at the [Use Picklists in Formulas](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/advanced_formulas/picklist_formulas) trailhead which shows how to combine this with `PRIORVALUE()`

Comment: Hi Rangelli, There is no Syntax error in the formula except the double quotations. Change `TEXT(Status)=”Activated”` to `TEXT(Status)="Activated"`. And make sure that workflow criteria is set as "created, and every time it’s edited "

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Another possibility is the use of "Smart quotes" rather that "straight quotes." "Smart quotes" are most likely introduced when copying/pasting from a Microsoft Office application or from a blog post not formatting their code snippets in the best way. *[EDIT: This is an expansion/explanation of what SaiPraveen Kakkirala posted in the comment above this one.]*

Comment: Thank you for the welcome and the answer! @Moonpie It was the " issue.. I was using a word doc to write the code. :| Do you have any code editors you can suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have some "smart quotes" in there, which will end up throwing some errors. That's unrelated to how to use picklists in formulas though.

In general, when you're working with picklists (such as your standard "Status" field), you need to use `ISPICKVAL()`. `TEXT()` can also work, [the Use Picklists in Formulas unit](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/advanced_formulas/picklist_formulas) on trailhead that Kris points to seems to indicate that both `ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(field), value))` and `TEXT(PRIORVALUE(field)) = value` would work.

The `ISCHANGED()` is also unnecessary here, since you're looking for a specific prior value. That is to say, if Status was "on hold" and now is "activated", `ISCHANGED()` would be true. You don't gain anything here by having that check.

So, to sum things up:

- Get rid of that `ISCHANGED()`, it's unnecessary
- `ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(<picklist field>), "target value")` or `TEXT(PRIORVALUE(<picklist field>)) = "target value")` should work. Pick one of those two styles, and stick with it. Be consistent throughout your org, and don't mix-and-match
- Be sure to use single-quotes <kbd>'</kbd> or double-quotes <kbd>"</kbd>, and not "smart" quotes. Again, pick one and use it consistently.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It was the " issue. I appreciate all the help here.. StackExchange has helped me more times than I can count!

Comment: @Rangell fyi - it's valuable to upvote & accept answers that are helpful - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)